# Pipelined / Persistent HTTP

Tags: network

I have a question regarding pipelined HTTP, is that the same thing as a persistent HTTP connection. If not what exactly does it mean?

Comment: wikipedia? [http pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Persistent HTTP

Reuse your existing TCP connection, so do not open a new TCP connection per resource. This saves you round-trip times for the handshake as you would otherwise have 1 RTT for TCP connection setup and 1 RTT for HTTP request.

### Pipelined HTTP

Send multiple requests to the server in parallel. This requires persistent HTTP. It can further reduce the number of RTTs for retrieving content as the client's idle time reduces (less waiting for responses) and the server's idle time does too (less waiting for requests to respond on it).

### Note

Still you might experience non-ideal behaviour due to loss and TCP retransmit. [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) (a modification of Google's Spdy) deals with that by distributing requests cleverly over multiple TCP connections.

Comment: "HTTP/2 ... over multiple TCP connections" no it does not. HTTP/2 does use a single TCP connection but can *multiplex* several *streams* (basically, a request/response pair) on this single TCP connection.